# Play .flac chunks in Chrome & Firefox (works in Safari)

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, media-source, flac

I converted a wav file into several `.flac` chunks to play with [Media Source Extensions (MSE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) in the browser. I used ffmpeg and the following command to generate de chunks:

```
ffmpeg -i long_input_44100.wav -vn -ar 48000 -ac 2 -f segment -segment_time 5 long_input_44100_%03d.flac
```

Then I load the chunks with fetch and append them to the media source buffer. This works in Safari but not Chrome or Firefox.

```js
const root = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/SergioCrisostomo/version-files/'
const manifestName = 'long_input_44100.json';

const audio = document.querySelector("audio");

const mimeType = "audio/aac";
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", async function() {
  // URL.revokeObjectURL(audio.src);

  const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeType);
  const manifest = await fetch(root + manifestName)
    .then((res) => res.json());
  const flacChunks = manifest.playlists.flac;

  sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", function() {
    if (!sourceBuffer.updating && mediaSource.readyState === "open") {
      addChunk(flacChunks.shift());
    }
  });
  const addChunk = (next) => {
    if (!next) return;
    fetch(root + next)
      .then((res) => res.arrayBuffer())
      .then((data) => {
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data);
      });
  };

  addChunk(flacChunks.shift());
});
```

```html
<audio controls></audio>
```

jsFiddle (same as above) [here (link)](https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/2ew4v58d/3/)

---

**What can the problem be?** If I use one of the chunks directly in the `audio.src` it works to play that single chunk in Chrome and Safari. Everything works with Safari.

```html
<audio controls src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/SergioCrisostomo/version-files/long_input_44100_000.flac"></audio>
```

Comment: The [MSE Spec Intro](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/#introduction) references the [MSE-REGISTRY](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/byte-stream-format-registry.html), which defines the byte stream formats for MSE.  It's possible that FLAC is not supported by the spec, which may thus not be supported by the browsers.